# Is there any way to avoid using Handle

Tags: programming, quantlib

I was trying to replicate one example from

http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/ql-fx-option-simple.html

In QuantLib general practice is to use `Handle` to manage change in the observed variable. I am fine with that.

However for my case, I do not want to use `Handle` but want to use direct `pointer` (smart). So I replace below line -

```
Handle<Quote> underlyingH(boost::shared_ptr<Quote>(new SimpleQuote(in.S)));
```

with

```
boost::shared_ptr<SimpleQuote> underlyingH = boost::make_shared<SimpleQuote>(in.S);
```

With this I am getting error as -

```
/Users/aa.cpp:60:59: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'QuantLib::GarmanKohlagenProcess'
     boost::shared_ptr<GarmanKohlagenProcess> process(new GarmanKohlagenProcess(underlyingH, fTS, rTS, flatVolTS));
                                                          ^                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/ql/processes/blackscholesprocess.hpp:196:9: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'boost::shared_ptr<SimpleQuote>' to
      'const Handle<QuantLib::Quote>' for 1st argument
        GarmanKohlagenProcess(
        ^
/usr/local/include/ql/processes/blackscholesprocess.hpp:194:11: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 4 were
      provided
    class GarmanKohlagenProcess : public GeneralizedBlackScholesProcess {
          ^
1 error generated.
```

Is there any way to not use Handle?

Many thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor of `GarmanKohlagenProcess` takes a `Handle`, so if you really want to avoid it you'll have to modify the constructor (and the type of the corresponding data member it initializes).

Comment: Thanks Luigi for this information

Comment: Is there any way to writing the same line as something like `underlyingH = ...` instead `underlyingH(...)`

Comment: `Handle<Quote> underlyingH = Handle<Quote>(...)`, or `auto underlyingH = Handle<Quote>(...)` if you're using C++11 or later